# Server.TransferRequest for IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, error-handling, iis-6, http-status-code-404

Is there a way to fake the behavior of TransferRequest in IIS 6? Specifically the ability to re-process the whole pipeline without the client having to make a new request?

I'm trying to handle a 404 error from Application_Error, do some magic to see if the URL changed (in which case I use Response.Redirect to redirect to the new URL) but if there really is a 404 I want to serve up my pretty looking 404 page which has to deal with showing some content which is part of the users session.

The problem is that if I use Server.Transfer, The request context is null at this point so my 404 page crashes. I don't want to use Request.Redirect because I want the browser URL to still be on the missing URL so the 404 status code gets interpreted properly for the missing resource.

On IIS 7 I can use TransferRequest which does exactly what I want. The browser retains the missing URL and Session context is available for the 404 page code. So is there a way to do something similar with IIS 6? (TransferRequest is only available in IIS 7 in Pipeline mode and our production servers are still on IIS 6)

Comment: I wish I had IIS6 laying around to actually try this; I can't believe that the this.Request.Context is null at that point (unless the error occurred within app_start). You don't say how/why you're using request-context. Did you try HttpContext.Current instead? I know that once in the past, at some weird point of execution, I discovered that this.Context (or maybe it was this.Request) was throwing an exception, while HttpContext.Current/HttpContext.Current.Request was returning a correct value.

Comment: @Hari The problem isn't that HttpContext.Current is null but that HttpContext.Current.Session is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to make your redirect with a flag, and then make RewritePath on BeginRequest.

For example, you place this code on `Global.asax`

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.EndsWith("error"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("404CoolPage.aspx", false);
    }


    // .... rest code   
}
```

and you make the redirect on your

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

    //... code

    if(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Count > 0)        
        Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl + "&error");
    else
        Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl + "?error");   
}
```

This way, you make the redirect, and you keep the url as it is.

### My Error Setup

By the way, I use the the Server.Transfer and Its working to me. This is my Error setup and the Transfer is done using the server, I am not sure where your page have problem with the request context

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // ... log the errors ...
    string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;
    // in case the error is inside the 404CoolError.aspx
    // I check for not calling my self and get a dead loop.
    if(!cTheFile.EndsWith("404CoolError.aspx"))
        Server.Transfer("~/404CoolError.aspx");
}
```

and on web.config

```
<customErrors redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" ... />
```

Comment: I think this answer provides the best options for my particular situation. In the end I actually went with removing any dependency on `HttpContext.Current.Session` from my 404 page so that Server.Transfer worked.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather there is no standard way to simulate `TransferRequest` on IIS 6 - at least not without a major rewrite of most of your code.

the only other options available (besides `Transfer` which you pointed out that it does not do what you need) are:

- [`Excute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23e7sy74.aspx)
- [`RewritePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa5wkk6d.aspx)

I would suspect that with some fiddling you could create a solution which is as close as you can get with IIS6 using `Execute` although I am not sure that performance will be good.

Regarding `RewritePath` you could start with with something like this and extend it to to do what you want:

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(url, false);
IHttpHandler httpHandler = new YourHTTPHandler(); // use your HttpHandler !
httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
```

Comment: I think I had tried something like this, but I would have to create a custom HTTPHandler because the default ASP.net one must be called asyncronously. I didn't really understand why I should write my own when I want mostly the default behavior.

Comment: @thelsdj basically you want to achieve something that is NOT built-in, at least not into IIS6... AFAIk there is no secret method to make IIS6 do what IIS7 can do... so you either upgrade to IIS7 or do some "extra work" (like the custom HttpHandler)...

Comment: I already upvoted this answer, but I'd love to see some example code for what a basic implementation of a HTTPHandler for this purpose would be.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a custom error handler in IIS. In the web site properties page, on the custom errors tab, edit '404' and set it to '404.aspx' (or whatever). Move your 'magic' code to the 404 page. If you find a real 404, then there is no need to 'transfer' anywhere - just let your page display.

Comment: What if the 404.aspx that also runs a code, throw an 404 error ? dead loop ?

Comment: If it throws an error you can't handle (which should be very rare, I hope) you can redirect to a plain html page so the user will see *something*. This could be done within the 404.aspx page itself, or in the global error handler.

Comment: The problem with allowing the Application_Error to fall through to the IIS error handler in IIS 6 is that it redirects the browser to /404.aspx?aspxerror=/originalpage.aspx. And thus this defeats the purpose of having the 404 status code show for the original resource.