# Server.Transfer, session state null

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

Why is the session state null when you use Server.Transfer? Is there anyway to enable the session? (session state is already enabled and working fine, it's just that HttpContext.Current.Session is null when you Server.Transfer into a new page within the same site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="NewPage" **EnableSessionState="True"** %>
```

May be try this as well: `Context.RewritePath` instead of sever.transfer

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a duplicate or just very similar. However, it does look a lot like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093023/server-transferrequest-for-iis-6)

Either way, it looks like somebody already had a bear of a time with it or else it would not have had a 200 point bounty :). So, hopefully you can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if the enableSessionState="true" is set in the page tag in the web.config?

Comment: It's already enabled, tried Inproc, Stateserver etc. SessionState is always null when you use Server.Transfer.